# SQL comparison query speed

Tags: sql, query-performance

I have a table of purchases:

```
id_purchase, date (timestamp), city ($), price, ...
15484, 1516004158, Phoenix, 147.56, ...
14879, 1516097654, Chicago, 47.99, ...
14788, 1515931918, New Yokr, 87.45, ...
```

And I need to create week to week comparison for ten cities with the most purchases.

```
WITH 
w1 AS
(SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE relative date limitation),
w2 AS
(SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE relative date limitation),
top_cities
(SELECT city FROM w2 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY count(*) DESC)

SELECT w2.city, 
w1.count(*),
w2.count(*),
(w2.count(*)/w1.count(*))-1)*100.00 AS Ratio
FROM w1, w2
WHERE w1.city IN (SELECT * FROM top_cities)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 4 ASC
```

But the query is slow, so I get an error because of timeout limit.

I would like to get result looks like this:

```
city, w1, w2, Ratio
Chichago, 245, 274, 11.84
Phoenix, 147, 197, 34.01
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please include a representative data sample and the desired result.

Comment: I've updated my post.

Comment: You can't have dynamic columns, even with a `PIVOT` statement in "pure" T-SQL. Your data will be better-consumed as rows instead.

Comment: What is the "ten cities with the most purchases." rule, exactly? Is that the top 10 cities in each week (so the cities themselves could change each week), or the top 10 cities over all time? Is there a ranking order? What if a city has lots of sales in one week and zero for the rest of the year?

Comment: "query speed" question without displaying the query plan.  Also note, the query planner may not optimize `WITH` queries

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: There is also no timestamp (or date) in your sample data. Where do you get the week from?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with - it will output data as rows which is easier to consume from application code and you can filter and process it further.

The schema does not match your question's desired output because you asked for "top 10 cities" but your code only outputs data as two explicit named columns, so it's very unclear about how you want that to work.

This is written in T-SQL for MS SQL Server 2000 or later. Most other database systems should be able to use this if you replace the square brackets `[` `]` with backticks and `EXTRACT( )` instead of `YEAR` and `DATEPART`.

```
SELECT
    city,
    YEAR( [date] ) AS [year],
    DATEPART( wk, [date] ) AS [weekNumber]
    COUNT(*) AS [count]
FROM
    purchases
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            TOP 10
            city,
            COUNT(*) AS [count]
        FROM
            purchases
        GROUP BY
            city
        ORDER BY
            [count] DESC
    ) AS top10Cities ON purchases.city = top10Cities.city
GROUP BY
    city,
    YEAR( [date] ),
    DATEPART( wk, [date] )
```

This query is better understood by reading it inside-out: start with the innermost subquery `top10Cities` that finds the top 10 cities, then it uses those city names to restrict the rows returned that aggregate all purchases by week-number. Converting week-number to actual dates is a view-level concern and not something that should be done inside SQL, in my opinion.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Amended.